# Skyrim Indoor lighting deactivated?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I was meesing with the skyrimpref.ini file to stop shadows from moving with my camera and finally ended up removing shadows altogether. But now the interiors of most houses do not have indoor lighting or have light on only half the room. How do i bring back lights without bringing back shadows or mods?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this shadow problem by changing ishadowquarter to 3